# How I can connect to snowflake using scala slick jdbc

Tags: scala, akka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, akka-stream, slick-3.0

I am using scala and akka stream for my application and finally want to insert the record to snowflake.

Is it possible to connect to snowflake using slick jdbc or alpakka slick .

Please assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, Snowflake is not in the list of supported databases:

https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.2/supported-databases.html

Comment: Is there any other way to connect to snowflake in scala?

Comment: Well, I think technically it is possible with Slick, you just have to write all the queries yourself instead of using Slick's query DSL. But at that point you have to ask yourself why you're even using Slick. Another commonly-used database library is Doobie.

Comment: Thanks, Matthias, I will check out Doobie as well